# Redis server started, but killed in a second

Tags: redis, ubuntu-server

I created 500 MB `rdb` file on OS X machine and Redis server works fine there. But on Ubuntu Server it is killed in several seconds after having started:

````
$ src/redis-server configFile_6381.conf

[1004] 30 Jan 15:50:27.591 * Max number of open files set to 10032
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 2.6.17 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in stand alone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6381
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1004
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

[1004] 30 Jan 15:50:27.593 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.17
Killed
````

Config file (`configFile_6381.conf`):

```
daemonize yes
pidfile /var/run/redisVgo.pid
port 6381
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 0
loglevel verbose
logfile /root/Dropbox/redis/_projects/vgo/vgo.log
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename vgo6381.rdb
dir ./
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
appendonly no
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

Sometimes before killing I see message in client output:

```
   (error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
```

Comment: Do these help? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/2n_9k4qoUJ8 & https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/3PFjBriTyZw

Comment: @Agis "LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory" - is usual message when you got to load large `.rdb` file. It is ok. The wierd thing is that then I see message "Connection refused"

Comment: Have you noticed the `(error)` part in the message?

Comment: @Agis I tested this rdb file on `mac os x` machine and got result ` 127.0.0.1:6382> ping
(error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
127.0.0.1:6382> ping
PONG` So after `(error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory` I got successfull ping pong. But not on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you run the same Redis version on both systems.

I used different Redis versions, which caused the trouble. On OS X it was 2.8, on Ubuntu Server it was 2.6. After I set up Redis 2.8 on Ubuntu Server, my .rdb file started there well.

Answer (score 0):

I was running in a similar issue and it seems that my dump.rdb was corrupted. If you do not care about the data currently loaded in your Redis, you can simply remove /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb and restart redis-server.